# Not able to see GUI using Gnome in RHEL 7.2 deployed in Azure

Tags: linux, azure, redhat, rhel

I am new to Linux environment. I have created a VM in Azure which has RHEL 7.2. I have installed Gnome 3.22.3 in it using Putty. I am NOT able to see the GUI for it. Is it possible to do it? I searched quite a bit, but, didn't find anything concrete. I followed these commands.

1) yum group list

2) a) yum groupinstall 'Server with GUI'
   (After downloading)
   Is this ok [y/d/N]: y

3) yum groupinstall 'X Window System' 'GNOME'

4) systemctl set-default graphical.target

5) gnome-shell --version

6) Reboot.

Still not able to see the GUI.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Hi, jww. This question is related to a technology. A tag of "linux, azure, redhat, rhel" wouldn't be there if someone hadn't created them, something that tells me we 'can' ask it here. Also, I didn't know about the other stack exchange, thanks for helping me with that. I will take care of it, next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I am NOT able to see the GUI for it. Is it possible to do it?

We can **install** `xrdp` on your VM, and **add** port 3389 to NSG inbound rules, then we can use `mstsc` to RDP it.

```
sudo -s
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server
systemctl start xrdp.service
netstat -antup | grep xrdp
systemctl enable xrdp.service
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3389/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Here a blog about how to enable GUI for centos 7 in classic module, please refer to [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoft_azure_guide/2015/01/05/how-to-enable-desktop-experience-and-enable-rdp-for-a-centos-7-vm-on-microsoft-azure/).

---

**Update**:

Please follow this steps to install xrdp on your RHEL 7.2:

1.Install Gnome on RHEL 7.2 first:

```
yum group install "GNOME Desktop" "Graphical Administration Tools"
yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
reboot
```

2.Install and configure EPEL repository:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

3.Add nux repository:

```
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Or Manual:
`vi /etc/yum.repos.d/xrdp.repo`

```
[xrdp]
name=xrdp
baseurl=http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

4.Install xrdp:

```
yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server
systemctl start xrdp.service
```

Check it with this command:

```
netstat -antup | grep xrdp

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1784/xrdp-sesman    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1785/xrdp
```

Enable the service at system start up:

```
systemctl enable xrdp.service
```

Add port 3389:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3389/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Configure SELinux:

```
chcon --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp
chcon --type=bin_t /usr/sbin/xrdp-sesman
```

By the way, we should add port 3389 to NSG inbound rules:

[image]

Here is my result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Jason Ye - MSFT. This worked for me. The only issue I have now is that I am able to connect it through using mstsc but after every 10 seconds the mstsc disconnects itself. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @RavishRawat I am out of office now, I will check  it tomorrow and reply you:)

Comment: Bro, did you find it out?

Comment: @RavishRawat I have update my answer, please check it:)